# Moving text upwards in Jtextpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane, jscrollbar

In a **Jtextpane**(with in a Jscrollpane) whenever we enter text it will be printed from top to bottom,

is it possible to keep the scroll bar at the bottom and move old text upwards(enabling scrollbar) whenever a text is appended?

**e.g :** if user is at line 1 and types "xyz" and press ENTER . Scrollbar should be enabled and xyz should be moved upwards with caret at second line.So if user scrolls up he will be able to see "xyz".

The problem is similar to my previous questions. I am trying to make it clear to get an answer.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
public class TextPane extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
public static TextPane instance;
private static JTextPane terminal = new JTextPane();
private static JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextPane.getInstance().init();
        }
    });
}
private static TextPane getInstance() {
    if(null == instance){
        instance =  new TextPane();
    }
    return instance;
}
private EnterAction enterAction;

private void init() {
    terminal.setFont(new Font("Courier new", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    terminal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    terminal.setBackground(Color.black);
    terminal.setForeground(Color.white);
    terminal.addKeyListener(this);
    terminal.setCaretColor(Color.green);
    terminal.setDragEnabled(false);

    enterAction = new EnterAction();
    terminal.getInputMap().put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "enter");
    terminal.getActionMap().put("enter", enterAction);

    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) terminal.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
    scroll.setViewportView(terminal);
    add(scroll);     
    setTitle("Dummy");
    setSize(500 , 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);
}

class EnterAction extends AbstractAction {
   //I typed a single line (in first line) of text and pressed enter.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae ) {
        try {
            Document doc = terminal.getDocument();
            int car = terminal.getCaretPosition();

            //Currently i tried adding newlines to get scroll bar in order to hide previously displayed contents.
            for(int i=0 ; i< 35 ; i++){
               doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", null);
            }               
            terminal.setCaretPosition(car + 1); // To set the caret at second line.
            JScrollBar sb = scroll.getVerticalScrollBar();
            sb.setValue( sb.getMaximum());//to keep the scroll bar at bottom.(Any how above setCaretPositon() makes it not work).
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't text be added at the point of the cursor?  Consider adding an actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: what happens when you wrap your textpane inside a jscrollpane?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes text will be added at the point of cursor and am not trying to change that. In a normal Jtextpane **enter** will give a new line displaying the previous line also. What i ask is Enter will give a new line but i need to move the previously displayed lines upwards(hiding it). So the user has to scroll up manually to see it.

Comment: @Hirak I couldn't get you.

Comment: What I meant was, Put the JtextPane inside a JScrollPane and put the JScrollPane in your Jpanel. Now you can adjust the height and width of your JScrollPane to make sure there is a scrollbar after n-line of typing. The old data will go up and will be visible when the user scroll up

Comment: @Hirak My implementation is similar to that. I expect all the text to move upwards leaving only the last line to be visible in UI.

Comment: @madhu If you only ever want line of text to be visible then you need to set the height of the scrollpane to be the height of a single line of text. Again you have been asked several times to post code that demonstrates your problem. This is your 5-6th question on this topic. Quit wasting our time unless you can post code because your verbal description of the problem is confusing everybody.

Comment: @camickr Sorry for that i have posted my sample code.

Comment: You say you want to achieve "Moving text upwards in Jtextpane", but don't you really want to move the scroll pane down while letting the text pane do what it normally does?

Comment: @user1803551 How can i achieve it? Moving the scrollpane..

Comment: Take a look at `void javax.swing.JScrollBar.setValue(int value)`.

Comment: It's not clear how you want to scroll down. The scroller can function only if there are more lines than the view can display. You want to add empty lines at the end? This seems like a poor design choice.

Comment: @user1803551 Yes .. thats why am trying for a different design. in my example above without 'terminal.setCaretPosition(car + 1); ' the first line text will be hidden(i got what i need) but caret will be at end. Is it possible to hide the text without adding newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Some notes:

1. Like your example the code uses blank lines to fill up the document. Although in this example the lines are only ever added once when the text component is created.
2. The `invokeLater` is used in the EnterAction to add the code to the end of the Event Dispatch Thread. This makes sure that all updates to the Document have been completed and therefore the maximum value of the scrollbar will be correct.
3. I used a JTextArea because it is easy to control the size of the text area based on the number of blank lines you need to initialize the text area. If you use a JTextPane then you will need to do extra calculations to determine the actual size of the text pane so that the scrollbars work correctly.
4. As a bonus I created a simple NavigationFilter which will prevent the user from moving the caret to any of the blank lines at the end of the Document. This feature will also prevent text selection for any of those blank lines using the mouse.
5. It is still possible to delete the blank lines. So you may want to create a KeyBinding that does nothing when the "Delete" key is pressed.
6. The code to override the width of the frame is just to prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing the first time you enter any data in the text pane. You may want to consider to always display the scrollbar, since it will continually be visible after you add the first line of data anyway.

The Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class NavigationFilterSuffix extends NavigationFilter
{
    private int suffixLength;
    private Document doc;

    public NavigationFilterSuffix(int suffixLength, Document doc)
    {
        this.suffixLength = suffixLength;
        System.out.println(suffixLength);
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    public void setDot(NavigationFilter.FilterBypass fb, int dot, Position.Bias bias)
    {
        int endOfDocument = doc.getLength() - suffixLength + 1;
        fb.setDot(Math.min(dot, endOfDocument), bias);
    }

    public void moveDot(NavigationFilter.FilterBypass fb, int dot, Position.Bias bias)
    {
        int endOfDocument = doc.getLength() - suffixLength + 1;
        fb.moveDot(Math.min(dot, endOfDocument), bias);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        final JTextArea terminal = new JTextArea(15, 30);
        // add 14 new lines (one less than rows specified above
        terminal.setText("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        terminal.setFont(new Font("Courier new", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        terminal.setBackground(Color.black);
        terminal.setForeground(Color.white);
        terminal.setCaretColor(Color.green);
        terminal.setDragEnabled(false);
        terminal.setCaretPosition(0);

        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( terminal );

        Action enterAction = new EnterAction();
        terminal.getInputMap().put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "enter");
        terminal.getActionMap().put("enter", enterAction);

        terminal.setNavigationFilter(new NavigationFilterSuffix(terminal.getRows(), terminal.getDocument()));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Navigation Filter Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        Dimension d = frame.getSize();
        d.width += 20;
        frame.setSize(d);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    static class EnterAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae )
        {
            try
            {
                final JTextArea terminal = (JTextArea)ae.getSource();
                Document doc = terminal.getDocument();
                int car = terminal.getCaretPosition();
                doc.insertString(car, "\n", null);

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane)SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, terminal);
                        JScrollBar sb = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                        sb.setValue( sb.getMaximum());
                    }
                });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code as per the conversation above. Please check if this solves your purpose.

```
public class ThingDoer extends JPanel {

    public ThingDoer() {
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(1, 10);
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(text,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
                );
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new ThingDoer());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(200, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the EDIT..I have added a sample code for the problem i face .